# Using soundpool in fragment/tab for soundboard app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a soundboard app in which i want to use soundpool in one of the fragment/tab and i am stuck at getSystemService for audiomanager.even after successful apk build app is not working. Here is my fragment class code. Thanks in advance.

```
public class FragmentQuiz extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ListView listView;
    int[] soundArray;
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int soundID;
    boolean loaded  = false;
    private int MAX=1;
    View view;

    Context context=getContext();


    public FragmentQuiz() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_fragment, container, false);

       soundArray = new int[5];
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener(){
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {

                loaded = true;
            }

        });

        soundArray[0] = soundPool.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bird,1);
        soundArray[1] = soundPool.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.raw.rooster,1);
        soundArray[2] = soundPool.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.raw.elephant,1);


        this.soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });


        AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float actualVolume = (float) audiomanager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float maxvolume =(float) audiomanager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(audiomanager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        final float volume = actualVolume / maxvolume;



       listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
       String[] values = new String[]{
               "Android Lollipop", "beta","marshmello"
       };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int itemPosition = position;
                String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "position: "+itemPosition + "ListItem: "+itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                soundPool.play(soundArray[position], volume, volume , 1,0,1f);
            }
        });




        return view;
    }

    private void setVolumeControlStream(int streamMusic) {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line **Context context=getContext();** is erroneous. This is you won't have access to **Context** until your fragment is instantiated. You should instead call it from your **onCreateView(...)** method. You could even just directly use **getContext()** from within that  method instead of instantiating a variable.

```
Context context;
public FragmentQuiz() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
    container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = getContext();
}
```

Also, since you're working in a fragment, you can't just do this

```
AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

This is because a Fragment isn't a subclass of **Context** (Like how an **Activity** is, and as such you don't have access to the **getSystemService(...)** method. Instead, you should do this:

```
AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Here's your initial code with all these changes made. I haven't tested it but it should work.

```
public FragmentQuiz() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_fragment, container, false);

soundArray = new int[5];
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {

        loaded = true;
    }

});

soundArray[0] = soundPool.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bird,1);
soundArray[1] = soundPool.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.raw.rooster,1);
soundArray[2] = soundPool.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.raw.elephant,1);


this.soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        loaded = true;
    }
});


AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) 
getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
float actualVolume = (float) audiomanager
        .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float maxvolume =(float) audiomanager
        .getStreamMaxVolume(audiomanager.STREAM_MUSIC);
final float volume = actualVolume / maxvolume;



listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
String[] values = new String[]{
       "Android Lollipop", "beta","marshmello"
};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,values);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int itemPosition = position;
        String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "position: "+itemPosition + "ListItem: "+itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        soundPool.play(soundArray[position], volume, volume , 1,0,1f);
    }
});




return view;
}

    private void setVolumeControlStream(int streamMusic) {}
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as the correct one if it solved your problem.